# Search keywords in row and take specific data

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help: I have an excel database wich look like that

```
ID product    ID article    Value A    Type of value A     Value B    Type of value B

Product 1     Article w     Red        PRODUCT             High       ARTICLE
Product 1     Article x     Red        PRODUCT             Low        ARTICLE
Product 2     Article y     Blue       ARTCILE             Low        PRODUCT
Product 2     Article z     Yellow     ARTICLE             Low        PRODUCT
```

The thing is, when Value A (or B) are the same when the ID product correspond, the Type of value is "PRODUCT" but when these values are not equal, the type is "ARTICLE".

Now I'd like to transform this table in 2 sheets (exemple below).

Sheet PRODUCT:

```
ID product   Value A     Value B    

Product1     Red        
Product1     Red
Product2                 Low
Product2                 Low
```

Sheet ARTICLE:

```
ID article    Value A    Value B

Article w                High
Article x                Low
Article y     Blue
Article z     Yellow
```

Of curse, I have more than 2 value. Some help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT 1**

- 1 product is related to 1 to n article (with n probably < 10)
- Data starts in A2 with my 2 ID column (product id = global ID and article ID = unique ID
- there is are than 2 value (A to B): it's more like A to Z

Comment: Does it need to be VBA, this can be done via formula

Comment: VBA would be easier for me, because  I'll need to use VBA to write the formula in every colum. I think VBA would be quicker. Thanks for your reactivity!

Comment: You could use array formula and have the two o/p sheets as static.  What VBA have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to loop through rows and columns, but I have too many "type of value" (30) and I don't know how to "keep in memory" all the value the maccro find. Or I could try something with filters but it would take too much time.

Comment: post what you tried, and why it didn't suit, then people will assist, people wont answer if they think you want code written with no effort to date.

Comment: I will do it, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

here is what I've got

```
Public nb_visuel As Integer
Public nb_doc As Integer
Public nb_url As Integer


Sub insert_col_alterné_et_formules()
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'random coments
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Var pour insertion colonnes.
Dim cible As Integer
Dim colonne As Integer
'Var pour remplissage colonnes.
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim compteur As Integer
Dim col As String
'Initialisation pour remplissage colonnes.
Sheets("Données").Select
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données")
LastRow = sht.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

UF_1.Show 'cible is my number of column I ask to the user
cible = (14 + (nb_visuel * 2) + (nb_doc * 2) + (nb_url * 2)) * 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For colx = 13 To cible Step 2
    Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next

'Fill the title.
For colonne = 13 To cible
    Cells(1, colonne).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Comparaison " & Cells(1, colonne - 1)
    End If
Next

'Insert formulas.
For r = 2 To LastRow
    For c = 13 To cible Step 2
        col = Split(Cells(r, c - 1).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        If Cells(r, c - 1) = "" Then
            Cells(r, c) = "PRODUIT"
        Else
            Cells(r, c).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C" & r & ")=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C" & r & ",$" & col & ":$" & col & "," & col & r & "),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE"")"
        End If
    Next
Next

'Copy/paste values.
Range("L2:BZ" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call traitement_marque 'Insert the fomrula to a particular column.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Finish!", 64 + vbYesNo, "Information"
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```